# Create API Resource Model for Value Objects

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

Is it safe to return Value Objects from an API endpoint or should all objects be converted to a Resource Model. For example if I have `GET /api/customers/123`
which retrieves a Customer model of

Customer

- ID
- Name
- Occupation

Occupation

- Code
- Description

Should I create a Resource Model for Customer and for Occupation? OR should I flatten Occupation on the Customer Resource Model? I feel like I'm creating models just for the sake of it when my value objects never have any properties that should not be exposed to the client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view there is no value in mapping value objects to resource models just for the sake of mapping.

I do map in the following cases:

- My value object contains sensitive data
- My value object contains to much data (so even though it's not sensitive data, it would just waste bandwidth)
- My value object is not suitable to what the consumer of my api needs. So in this case I do often combine data from several value objects into a resource model